# CakePHP how to structure the array output find data format

Tags: php, cakephp

any one guide me how to structure the array output from the cackephp find

In Mymodel->find( 
Condition with any format like sum() or Formatdate() or any other means i got that filed as seprate array with key [0] how can i restructure ?

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Mymodel] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 2014-12-28
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 200.00
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Mymodel] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 2014-12-30
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 120.00
                )

        )
```

how do i merge this in to

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Mymodel] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 2014-12-28
                    [y] => 200.00
                )



        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [Mymodel] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 2014-12-28
                    [y] => 200.00
                )



        )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:
1. Put `COUNT()` AS virtual field named y
2. Use `afterFind` to merge array, You can use [`Hash::combine()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::combine)